# How to read only a piece of a text file name? And compare it with a string in a textBox?

Tags: c#, directory

I have a program that create a `.txt` file depending on which button the user cliks. If you click the `Button A` it will create a `.txt` file with this name : `BA_12345678912345678`. Instade, If you click the `Button B` it will create a `.txt` file with this name: `BB_48654321546875684`

(The number will change between clicks, depend of the time and others things. And the amount of numbers always will be 17)

This files will create in a path (for this case will be: `C:\Users\Desktop\Folder1`) and can be only 5 files in this `Folder1`.

In the same program I have a `textBox` that I am write on it the number of the file that I want to open.

How I can read only the numbers of the `.txt` files and compare with the string on the `textBox`?

Comment: Have you considered using Regex.Match ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Zze I will try...Thanks for answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always 17 digits, you can simply use `substring` to get the numbers part of the string:

```
var numbers = textFileName.Substring(textFileName.Length - 17);
```

if you know the first part is always 3 chars long you can do this:

```
var numbers = textFileName.Substring(3);
```

if you know that there is always a single underscore char folowed by numbers, you can do this:

```
var numbers = textFileName.Substring(textFileName.IndexOf("_") + 1);
```

**Update**

To get the list of files in a directory you can use [`System.IO.Directory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var filesList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Folder1");
// filesList now is an array of strings containing all the file names (including path) in the C:\Users\Desktop\Folder1 directory.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me, but How can I compare with the names of the files inside the folder? Don't I need a Directory?...I'm newbie in this kind of programation...

Comment: use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the list of files in a directory.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Because I been try with this and doesn't work...

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I modified the code for my own purposes, and It works. Thanks again...